# Jframe pegado a otro Jframe

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

Buenas!

Tengo que hacer que primero salga un jFrame [el negro] con un comboBox que hara que, dependiendo de la opcion elegida, salga un 2do jFrame [el verde], pero quiero que siempre que se genere el 2do jframe, sea 'anclado' asi a la base del 1er jframe, asi como la imagen.

Lo "facil" seria decir que mi 1er jframe siempre aparezca en cierto punto, y en base a eso, aparecer el 2do, pero yo quiero, aparte, que al arrastrar el 1er o 2do jframe, se muevan ambos.

Espero explicarme. Gracias de antemano.

[image: jFrames]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tendrias que hacer es tener un frame general, y dentro dos contenedores(JPanel) en donde vayas colocando tus componentes:
En el constructor de tu clase que extienda JFrame:

```
........
setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600); 
getContentPane().setLayout(null);
JPanel contentPanel1 = new JPanel(); 
contentPanel1.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 300); 
getContentPane().add(contentPanel1); 
contentPanel1.setLayout(null);
JPanel contentPanel2 = new JPanel(); 
contentPanel2.setBounds(0, 300, 400, 300); 
getContentPane().add(contentPanel2); 
contentPanel2.setLayout(null);
```

Dentro de esos contenedores vas colocando los componentes que desees. La posicion de cada contenedor lo manejas con el método **setBounds(x, y, width, height)**. Donde **x** e **y** son los puntos de inicio, y los otros dos son el ancho y alto del contenedor